# how to print category and sub-category limit 3 set only sub-category

Tags: php

```
<div class="row">
    <?php $category = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from category  ORDER BY title ASC");while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($category)) {?>
    <div class="category-box" style="width:18%;margin-right:2%; float:left; height:300px;position: relative;">
        <?php $image=$row['image'];if(empty($image)){$image="defualt.jpeg"; }?>
        <img src="myhomeportal/vendors/category-img/<?php echo $image;?>" width="100%; height:150px;">
        <h4 class="category-title"><?php echo mb_strimwidth ($row['title'], 0, 15, "...");?></h4>
        <a href="show-subcategories.php?cat_id=<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>" class="cat_id_view"><button class="btn btn-primary">View More</button></a>
        <?php $subcat=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE (issue here how to set limit 3) cat_id=".$row['cat_id'] );while($row=$subcat->fetch_array()){ ?>
            <a href="show-childcategories.php"><h5 class="subcategory-title1"><?php echo mb_strimwidth ($row['title'], 0, 15, "...");?></h5></a>
        <?php }?>
    </div>      
<?php }?></div>
```

Comment: Please properly format your code.

Comment: `<button>` inside `<a>`, is that valid?

Comment: (issue here how to set limit 3)

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code

Comment: @kerbholz I think so, but is pointless

Comment: all is well only set limit

Comment: working fine but sub-category show all data but i want to show only 3

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE cat_id=".$row['cat_id']." LIMIT 3";` but who knows need latest sub category or oldest

Comment: <?php $subcat=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE (issue here how to set limit 3) cat_id=".$row['cat_id'] );while($row=$subcat->fetch_array()){ ?>
            
        <?php }?>

Comment: <?php $subcat=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE limit 3 cat_id=".$row['cat_id'] );while($row=$subcat->fetch_array()){ ?>
            
        <?php }?>

Comment: error msg->Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in D:\xammp\htdocs\listing\show-categories.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xammp\htdocs\listing\show-categories.php on line 22

Comment: your query formation is not correct, check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, you cant use `LIMIT` before `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE limit 3 cat_id=".$row['cat_id']
```

This should be:

```
SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE cat_id=".$row['cat_id']." LIMIT 3";
```

**Formation must be:**

```
SELECT
FROM
WHERE
LIMIT
```

**Side Note:** But, this will return ist 3 records not latest three records.

**[Useful link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm)**